# Compare Visual Studio 2013 and 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

What are the differences between Visual Studio 2013 and 2015?

I am looking for a comparison table of features.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx